# Create TableLayout programmatically

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm trying to create a TableLayout programatically. It just won't work. The same layout in an xml file works though. This is what I have:

```
public class MyTable extends TableLayout
{
    public MyTable(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button b = new Button(getContext());
        b.setText("hello");
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.addView(b); 
        addView(row)
    }
}

...

// In main activity:
MyTable table = new MyTable(this);
mainLayout.addView(table);
```

When I run this, I don't get a crash, but nothing appears. If I get rid of the TableRow instance, at least the button does appear as a direct child of the TableLayout. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 42):

Just to make the answer more clear:

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));// assuming the parent view is a LinearLayout

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);// TableLayout is the parent view

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);// TableRow is the parent view

tableRow.addView(textView);
```

**Explanation**
When you call `setLayoutParams`, you are supposed to pass the `LayoutParams` of the parent view

Comment: Shouldn't it be tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowParams) ?

Comment: The life saver award goes to @Gigori A. and mark. Gigori A. for this answer and mark for his own answer.

Comment: Great and helpful solution. As a side note, you should add the row to the table before you add the textview to the row. tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

Comment: Spent an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong - turns out in your code you missed adding `tableRow` to the `tableLayout`: `tableLayout.addView(tableRow);`

Comment: @The_Martian. actually, that's not mandatory. it also works first filling the row and then adding the latter to the table. In my strict opinion, that is more intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I needed to specify TableRowLayout, TableLayout etc for the layout params, otherwise the table just won't show!

Comment: Can you post your code solution?  It looks like you are already doing that above.

Comment: Thank you! @Atma TableRows should use TableLayout.LayoutParams and views inside the TableRows should use TableRow.LayoutParams. :)

Comment: Horrible that you need to explicitly do this, but it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Brayden! That was the small detail I missed in my subclass of TableLayout that automatically had all TableLayout.LayoutParams and not TableRow.LayoutParams!

Answer (score 1):

For me, to get mine I had to call `addContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to inflate layout files for each instance of row you want to create. See this post : [How to duplicate Views to populate lists and tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662844/how-to-duplicate-views-to-populate-lists-and-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this line:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You need to change `LayoutParams` to `TableRow.LayoutParams`:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```