# LinearLayout not updating with TableLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout that I programmatically update with a TableLayout using the code:

```
public void updateTableView(MyData data){
  DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(getApplicationContext(), data);
  LinearLayout placeHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_view);
  placeHolder.addView(dataTable);
}
```

(For more background see [Android RelativeLayout alignment based on View added programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421709/android-relativelayout-alignment-based-on-view-added-programmatically/15421832?noredirect=1#15421832).)

The first time the method `updateTableView` is called it works fine. But the LinearLayout seems to be ignoring all subsequent calls. I know this because the `data` is different each time but the app is only showing the result of the first call to `updateTableView`, i.e. the view is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you don't remove previously added `DataTable` views. Try calling `removeView()`:

```
private DataTable dataTable;

public void updateTableView(MyData data) {
  if (dataTable != null) {
      placeHolder.removeView(dataTable);
  }
  dataTable = new DataTable(getApplicationContext(), data);
  LinearLayout placeHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_view);
  placeHolder.addView(dataTable);
}
```

Comment: Cool! It's working now. I just call `removeAllViews()` for my specific case.

Comment: Great. Sorry I had a bug in my code, removeView should be called first(so that it removes the old one not the new one). I updated my code now.